# What is this wire going from mid-fuselage to the tail on this 737?

Tags: boeing-737

In  [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24686/4197) the following image is shown, with the question what the two bulges at the aft fuselage are.

However, I'm wondering what this wire is that starts somewhere midway the fuselage, and goes to the vertical stabilizer.
Is it also radar related?
[image]
[image]

[Image Source](http://www.b737.org.uk/737original.htm)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the HF antenna. It was mostly used in older aircraft, which used them in trans-oceanic flights or in areas without UHF or VHF communications facilities.Modern 737s (and other aircraft in general) have done away with them. On later versions it was fitted in the leading edge of the Vertical fin of B737-200s, as shown in the figure below.

[image: B737 antenna]

Image from b737.org.uk

Note that these aircraft were delivered in 1982-83. Newer 737s don't have these.

Comment: So the wire was a part of the HF antenna? And the newer version don't need this wire anymore?

Comment: @ROIMaison Yes. The new antenna looks something like [this](http://www.qrz.com/db/DF1CHB)

Comment: @aeroalias: That page seems to require an account to see it. Do you have any references that don't require an account?

Comment: @user2357112 Thats wierd. There seems to be no problem for me. Anyway, see [this](http://www.google.com/patents/US7511674).

Comment: When you say "newer 737s don't have these," you're referring just to the long external wire antennas, not HF antennas in general, right? AFAIK, nearly all airliners still have HF antennas for the purposes you mentioned (i.e. trans-oceanic routes and such.)

Comment: You can tell it is an older-model 737 by the engine nacelle shape as well. (photo posted by OP)

Comment: Apparently, for smaller planes the HF antenna is something that one could spool out.  A [Cessna 150 flying across the Atlantic](http://www.cessna150-152.com/transatlantic.htm) includes a bit about it *not* working (it got tangled).  "The 150 had also been fitted with an HF including an antenna tuning mechanism and a trailing aerial." --- just to get another idea of that antenna on other planes.

Comment: @reirab Yes. I meant the external wire antennae. They've been shifted to the vertical fin, it seems.

Comment: What is the purpose of HF antenna on the  airplane except for HF communication?

Comment: @Arian - HF radios have to be used for trans-oceanic flights because VHF and UHF radios can not provide the increased range accomplished by bouncing the radio signal off of the ionosphere.

Answer (score 4):

It is an HF (High Frequency) antenna. It is used for aircraft to communicate on overseas flights. VHF (Very High Frequency) airband radios are used for normal local and cross country flights.

For a radio to transmit effectively, the internal components of the radio and the external (to the radio) antennae both have to match the frequency used for the transmission. If either does not match, the signal will not go out as strong nor as far. The way the antennae match is by having an antenna that corresponds to the wavelength of the signal. The way you determine the length based on the signal frequency is by dividing 234 by the frequency in megahertz. This gives you your antennae length in feet. Therefore, the higher the frequency, the shorter the antenna needed.

For this next section, we will relate the radio wavelength to energy. The higher the frequency, the shorter the wavelength. In our examples, the shorter the wavelength, the more “energy” the radio wave (or signal) has.

The reason this is important is that radio signals travel in straight lines. They are just like light. They require a lot of energy to punch through obstacles. If the radio receiver is in the radio “shadow” of an obstacle, it will not receive the signal. Since the Earth is curved, this limits the distance a particular radio wave can be received from its source. The line-of-sight (straight line seeing) distance of an observer standing on the Earth’s surface in flat terrain is only 60 miles.

One way to combat this is to use lower frequencies. Frequencies of less than 30 MHz do not have enough of the required energy to punch through the protective obstacle surrounding the Earth called the ionosphere. Instead, the signal gets reflected back down towards the Earth where it gets reflected back up again. The signal will then bounce between sky and Earth for as long as it has energy to travel. Sort of like a billiard ball.

When traveling extremely long distances, like overseas, you have to utilize this signal bouncing feature of HF radios to reach your intended recipient. Radios in the UHF and VHF range can only be used as line-of-sight transmitters because, at frequencies above 30 MHz, the wavelength of their signals will punch through the ionosphere and not get reflected back down to Earth.

P.S. HF antennae can be bent or folded to accommodate less space. The antenna length can even be divided in half or fourth, but may induce frequency matching errors. Dividing it by eighth will compound those errors too much to make it useable in many cases. Any other division will make the antennae not match. To compensate for smaller antennae, internal components of the radio and electrical ballasts and counter-poises on the antennae are used to compensate for the shorter length.